# Xcode Unable to run app in Simulator NSPOSIXErrorDomain, Code = 22

Tags: xcode, xcode6

Project builds, Simulator launches, app doesn't run in Simulator (Xcode 6.0.1)

- Tried reseting Simulator
- Tried downloading Simulators again

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed #generate_bridge_support! from Podfile